# How to display a number with varying decimal separator in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, numberformatter

After changing my OS's decimal separator as explained here:
( http://blogmines.com/blog/2010/03/11/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-in-excel-2010/ ), I want to display a number in Flex that uses a comma for both the thousands separator and the decimal separator. Sounds simple enough, right?

I tried using three different NumberFormatters offered by Flex. Along the way, I learned that two of them didn't play well with others in the same class, even if using fully qualified class paths when declaring the variables, so I had to split them up into three classes, like so:

NF1 - spark.formatters.NumberFormatter

```
package dstrube
{
    import flash.globalization.NumberParseResult;
    import spark.formatters.NumberFormatter;
    public class NF1
    {
        public static function get(value:String):String{
            var nf1:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();
            var result:NumberParseResult = nf1.parse(value);
            return nf1.format(result.value);
        }
    }
}
```

NF2 - flash.globalization.NumberFormatter

```
package dstrube
{
    import flash.globalization.NumberParseResult;
import flash.globalization.NumberFormatter;
    public class NF2
    {
        public static function get(value:String):String{
            var nf2:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter("");// LocaleID.DEFAULT = same outcome as without
            nf2.fractionalDigits = 2; //= same outcome as without
            nf2.trailingZeros = true;
            var result:NumberParseResult = nf2.parse(value);
            //nf2.parseNumber(value); = NaN
            return nf2.formatNumber(result.value)
        }
    }
}
```

NF3 - mx.formatters.NumberFormatter (deprecated)

```
package dstrube
{
    //import mx.formatters.NumberBaseRoundType;
    import mx.formatters.NumberFormatter;
    public class NF3
    {
    public static function get(value:String):String{
        var nf3:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();
        //nf3.rounding = NumberBaseRoundType.NEAREST; //no effect in this case
        return nf3.format(value);
    }
}
```

}

and finally, the main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="init()"
               >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import dstrube.NF1;
            import dstrube.NF2;
            import dstrube.NF3;
            [Bindable]
            public var s:String = "";
            protected  function init():void{
                var value:String = "5558049.90360013";
                s = "spark.formatters.NumberFormatter = " + NF1.get(value); //5,558,049.90
                s += "\n flash.globalization.NumberFormatter = " + NF2.get(value);//5,558,049,00
                s += "\n mx.formatters.NumberFormatter = " + NF3.get(value); //5,558,049.90360013
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
        <s:TextArea id="textArea" text="{s}" width="100%" height="100%" />
</s:Application>
```

The smartest of the three NumberFormatters is  flash.globalization.NumberFormatter for recognizing decimal separator, but it rounds incorrectly, showing 5,558,049,00 instead of 5,558,049,90

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either:

- Explicitly setting the formatter's properties will give you the
  output you require.
- Set the formatter to use the default locale.

  ```
          [Bindable] protected var formatted:String;

          protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
          {
              var formatter:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();

              // Option 1 set explicitly
              formatter.decimalSeparator = ",";
              formatter.fractionalDigits = 2;
              formatter.trailingZeros = true;

              // Option 2 set default locale to be the locale
              formatter.setStyle("locale", LocaleID.DEFAULT);

              formatted = formatter.format("5558049.90360013");
          }

      ]]>
  </fx:Script>

  <s:Label text="{formatted}" />
  ```

The output is "5,558,049,90".

Comment: Hmm, that is helpful, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to do this without having to specify the decimal separator in flex, but rather detect the OS's decimal separator. flash.globalization.NumberFormatter seems to be the only one that does this, but has the strange rounding error. 

I noticed that in spark.formatters.NumberFormatter, there is a property called actualLocaleIDName that is "en-us" when I have "English (United States)" selected in in Region and Language; but if I change this to something else like "French (Belgium", actualLocaleIDName doesn't change.

Comment: Ah-ha! I figured it out: 
Since flash.globalization.NumberFormatter can detect the OS's decimalSeparator but has bad rounding and since spark.formatters.NumberFormatter has good rounding but can't detect the OS's decimalSeparator, the solution is to use the spark formatter but set its decimalSeparator from flash.globalization. I'll post the solution presently.

Comment: However, I didn't explicitly specify in my original question that this has to use the decimal separator from the OS's settings, and your example helped lead me to the answer, so I'll say you win the bounty. Thanks for your help, Justin.

Comment: spark.formatters.NumberFormatter uses the flash.globalization.NumberFormatter under the hood and in most cases should get the decimal separator for the current Locale. I have noticed however on OSX it doesn't allways get it right. In my case localeChanged in GlobilizationBase is being called and the locale is being set to "en", not "en-AU" as I would expect. Flash takes "en" to mean "en-US" and changed the g11nWorkingInstance to use "en-US" in createWorkingInstance in NumberFormatter.

Comment: This may also be an answer: formatter.setStyle("locale", LocaleID.DEFAULT); formatted = formatter.format("5558049.90360013");

Answer (score 1):

This way will display whatever the decimal separator is set to be in the OS's settings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               initialize="init(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import spark.formatters.NumberFormatter;
            import flash.globalization.NumberFormatter;

            [Bindable] protected var formatted:String;

            protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var formatter:spark.formatters.NumberFormatter = new spark.formatters.NumberFormatter();
                var nf2:flash.globalization.NumberFormatter = new flash.globalization.NumberFormatter("");

                formatter.decimalSeparator = nf2.decimalSeparator;
                formatter.fractionalDigits = 2;
                formatter.trailingZeros = true;

                formatted = formatter.format("5558049.90360013");
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label text="{formatted}" />
</s:Application>
```